# Composition, belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, relation

I have a 1:n (person to city) relationship

Model Person:

```
 belongs_to :city
 composed_of :city, :mapping => %w(city_name city)
```

Model City:

```
  has_many :people
```

Now it should be possible to set the city: peson.city = "London" ?
Do I understand it or what is the purpose?

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Aggregations/ClassMethods.html

In the example they didnt use a has_many or belongs_to. Why?

Answer (score 0):

when you do

```
person.city = "London"
```

Rails sees this as `set city to the string 'London'` which is not correct.  What you want to tell Rails is to `set the city to the record in the database with a name of 'London'`.  You do that by (in simplest terms)

```
london = City.find_by_name 'London'
person.city = london
```